# How to make {multicols}{2} the same as \twocolumn ?

Tags: vertical-alignment, two-column, multicol

Using `\begin{multicols}{2}` gives me unexpected results. It seems like if I write 8 lines, then it divides by 2, then puts 4 lines in the left column and then the other 4 in the right column (see example 1).

What I really want is the layout that `\twocolumn` gives (see example 2). Only when the first column is entire filled then let text overflow to next column.

How do I make `\begin{multicols}{2}` to copy the text flowing behavior of `\twocolumn`?

**{multicols}{2}** :

```
example 1
# = text

-----HEADER------
####### | #######
####### | #######
####### | #######
####### | #######




-----FOOTER------
```

**\twocolumn** :

```
example 2
# = text

-----HEADER------
####### |
####### |
####### |
####### |
####### |
####### |
####### |
####### |
-----FOOTER------
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I expect that `\begin{multicols*}{2}` is what you're looking for. This doesn't try to balance the columns.